# Include a certain transient field in JSON serialization with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have this class

```
Myclass
{
  transient String field1;
  transient String field2;
  ... // other non transient fields
}
```

I store serialized objects, use them through network this way (transient fields excluded).

However, just for one particular case, I need to include field2 in serialization.

Is there a way to not to exclude a certain transient field in serialization using gson?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 0:**

Use a custom type adapter for the class.

Considering

```java
@JsonAdapter(KA.class)
class K{
    private transient String name;
    private transient String password;
}

class Entity_Adapter extends TypeAdapter<Entity>{
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Entity value) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        
        out.name("name");
        out.value(value.getName());
        
        out.name("password");
        out.value(value.getPassword());
        
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Entity read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        Entity k=new Entity();
        in.beginObject();
        
        in.nextName();
        k.setName(in.nextString());
        
        in.nextName();
        k.setPassword(in.nextString());
        
        in.endObject();
        return k;
    }
}
```

full example [here](https://gist.github.com/911992/03120393d31b24ed3c069c2698cde07d)

**Solution 1:** *(not robust)*

Add another non-`transient` field, and always copy any new set value for `field2` for it too. e.g.

```java
transient String field1;
transient String field2;

@SerializedName("field2")
private String field2_non_trans;

public void setField2(String arg_val){
this.field2 = arg_val;
this.field2_non_trans = arg_val;
}

public String getField2(){
  if(field2 == null){
    field2 = field2_non_trans;
  } 
  return field2;
}
```

full sample [here](https://gist.github.com/911992/8a4bb7f84beb974730eaaecb7885d967)

But you **MUST** track *every change* to that `field2`, to keep the copy of the val for `field2_non_trans` updated always, so if that `field2` is set by constructor, or out-of its `setter` function, you have to be sure you set the value copy for `field2_non_trans`

Same for deserializing, you have to either:

- once deserializing is over, you need to set the deserialized value of `field2_non_trans` to `field2` using a method.
- Or simply return `field2_non_trans` by `getField2()` method, where `field2` is `null`

**Solution 2:**

Mark that `field2` non-transient.

Comment: Solution 1 and 2 will produce a 'field2' field for other serializations, which is not ok in my case. But type adapter, sol. 0, looks promising, I'll look into it when i got the chance . Thanks.

Comment: Writing a custom adapter technically solves this problem, but its a tedious work when the class is big and it is a challenge to write it in a way that it is easy to maintain. +1 for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate your transient field with another non transient and write value from transient field setter. The idea is update clone field every time transient field updates.

Comment: Yes, but won't it produce a 'field2' field for other serializations? It is not ok for in my case. I think I need smt like a custom builder for this particular case

Answer (score 0):

Despite I would never recommend using the same class for different libraries due to issues like this, you can easily manage the way Gson applies [exclusion strategies](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html) to fields being serialized and deserialized.

```java
public final class TransientExclusionStrategy
        implements ExclusionStrategy {

    private static final ExclusionStrategy instance = new TransientExclusionStrategy();

    private TransientExclusionStrategy() {
    }

    public static ExclusionStrategy getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(final FieldAttributes attributes) {
        @Nullable
        final Expose expose = attributes.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
        if ( expose == null ) {
            return attributes.hasModifier(Modifier.TRANSIENT);
        }
        return !expose.serialize();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(final Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

This implementation would pass the following unit test:

```java
public final class TransientExclusionStrategyTest {

    private static final String EXPOSED = "EXPOSED";
    private static final String IGNORED = "IGNORED";

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    private static final class MyClass {

        final String s0 = EXPOSED; // no explicit expose, serialized by default

        @Expose(serialize = false)
        final String s1 = IGNORED; // ignored by annotation

        @Expose(serialize = true)
        final String s2 = EXPOSED; // serialized by annotation

        final transient String ts0 = IGNORED; // no explicit expose, ignored by default

        @Expose(serialize = false)
        final transient String ts1 = IGNORED; // ignored by annotation

        @Expose(serialize = true)
        final transient String ts2 = EXPOSED; // serialized by annotation

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(TransientExclusionStrategy.getInstance())
                .create();
        final JsonObject json = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(new MyClass());
        for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : json.entrySet() ) {
            final String stringValue = e.getValue().getAsString();
            Assertions.assertEquals(EXPOSED, stringValue, () -> "Expected " + EXPOSED + " but was " + stringValue + " for " + e.getKey());
        }
    }

}
```

Thus you don't need to handle any special type adapters for every such a "special" class or introduce intermediate fields (that's not necessarily not in conflict state with other libraries and frameworks you're using).